# How would I add a 3d cube at these coordinates? OpenGL11

Tags: java, opengl

I'm making a "waypoint mod" for Minecraft. The idea is a line will be drawn to the coordinates, and a 3d box(non-rotating) will be as well. Below is the line code.

```
  public void WaypointLine(boolean flag) {
    try {
    GL11.glBlendFunc(770, 771);
    GL11.glLineWidth(3F);
    GL11.glDisable(2929 /*GL_DEPTH_TEST*/);
    GL11.glDepthMask(false);

    GL11.glColor3f(255, 0, 0);

          double size = 0.45;
          double ytSize = 0.35;
          GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_LINES);

              double X = EntityClientPlayerMP.waypointX;
              double Y = EntityClientPlayerMP.waypointY;
              double Z = EntityClientPlayerMP.waypointZ;
              double mX = mc.thePlayer.posX;
              double mY = mc.thePlayer.posY;
              double mZ = mc.thePlayer.posZ;
              double dX = (mX - X);
              double dY = (mY - Y);
              double dZ = (mZ - Z);

              if(X != mX && Y != mY && Z != mZ) {        
                  GL11.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
                  GL11.glVertex3d((-dX + size) - 0.5, (ytSize - dY) + 1.0, (-dZ - size) + 0.5);
              }


          GL11.glEnd();    
    GL11.glDepthMask(true);
    GL11.glEnable(2929 /*GL_DEPTH_TEST*/);
      } catch (Exception e) {}
```

}

It works perfectly. I really don't have an idea of how to draw a cube though. How do I? Examples or resources please... I did some searching and had some trouble understanding.

Comment: Why are you using decimal enum values instead of the proper OpenGL token names? All OpenGL tokens are defined in hexadecimal, so it takes more work to figure out what these numbers mean when you write them in decimal (not that you should be doing that to begin with).

Comment: For god sake, replace those constants with something like: `GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA`, instead of `770`.

Answer (score 0):

Yay! Immediate mode ftw!

```
float sizeX = 100;
float sizeY = 200;
float sizeZ = 80;
float centerX = 20;
float centerY = 30;
float centerZ = 10;
float [] yay = {
  centerX-sizeX*.5,centerY+sizeY*.5,centerZ+sizeZ*.5,
  centerX-sizeX*.5,centerY-sizeY*.5,centerZ+sizeZ*.5,
  centerX+sizeX*.5,centerY-sizeY*.5,centerZ+sizeZ*.5,
  centerX+sizeX*.5,centerY+sizeY*.5,centerZ+sizeZ*.5,

  centerX-sizeX*.5,centerY+sizeY*.5,centerZ-sizeZ*.5,
  centerX-sizeX*.5,centerY-sizeY*.5,centerZ-sizeZ*.5,
  centerX+sizeX*.5,centerY-sizeY*.5,centerZ-sizeZ*.5,
  centerX+sizeX*.5,centerY+sizeY*.5,centerZ-sizeZ*.5,

  centerX+sizeX*.5,centerY+sizeY*.5,centerZ-sizeZ*.5,
  centerX+sizeX*.5,centerY-sizeY*.5,centerZ-sizeZ*.5,
  centerX+sizeX*.5,centerY-sizeY*.5,centerZ+sizeZ*.5,
  centerX+sizeX*.5,centerY+sizeY*.5,centerZ+sizeZ*.5,

  centerX-sizeX*.5,centerY+sizeY*.5,centerZ-sizeZ*.5,
  centerX-sizeX*.5,centerY-sizeY*.5,centerZ-sizeZ*.5,
  centerX-sizeX*.5,centerY-sizeY*.5,centerZ+sizeZ*.5,
  centerX-sizeX*.5,centerY+sizeY*.5,centerZ+sizeZ*.5,

  centerX+sizeX*.5,centerY+sizeY*.5,centerZ-sizeZ*.5,
  centerX-sizeX*.5,centerY+sizeY*.5,centerZ-sizeZ*.5,
  centerX-sizeX*.5,centerY+sizeY*.5,centerZ+sizeZ*.5,
  centerX+sizeX*.5,centerY+sizeY*.5,centerZ+sizeZ*.5,

  centerX+sizeX*.5,centerY-sizeY*.5,centerZ-sizeZ*.5,
  centerX-sizeX*.5,centerY-sizeY*.5,centerZ-sizeZ*.5,
  centerX-sizeX*.5,centerY-sizeY*.5,centerZ+sizeZ*.5,
  centerX+sizeX*.5,centerY-sizeY*.5,centerZ+sizeZ*.5};


GL11.glBegin(GL11.QUADS);
for(int i = 0; i < yay.length; i+=3) 
  GL11.glVertex3d(yay[i],yay[i+1],yay[i+2]);
GL11.glEnd();
```